# Using COM Object DLL in C# Application

Tags: com, dll

I have a COM Component  DLL.
I can use this DLL in VB.NET.
But I must configurate Project Properties Compile Settings.
I write "Win32=True" to  "Custom Constant" area and application succesfully run.
But I Cant find this configuration for C# application.

How can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Project + Properties, Build tab, "Conditional compilation symbols" box.